# Android Apps with Push Ads and Floating Ads

Tags: android, notification

Does anyone happen to know some Android apps with annoying Push Ads and Floating Ads? I plan to study Android Ads and want to get a list of exampled apps before conducting a large-scale empirical study.

Push Ads will trigger advertisement content on our notification panel. Floating Ads usually occupy a small part of the screen but can still be seen outside the app. Examples of Floating Ads:

[Example1](https://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/356868-help-ads-home-screen.html)

[Example2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123349/a-random-floating-ad-is-always-on-top)

[image: Floating Ad Example1]
[image: Floating Ad Example2]

Please share as many of those apps as possible with me. I appreciate your help.